# How to delete comments from templates in Laravel phpframework

Tags: laravel

Every developer writes comments in his  HTML, CSS or Javascript.
But I don't want my comments to be visible for other people.
I develop an web app with laravel php framework and I want to clear all comments from my code as:

```
// comment 
/* comment */
<!-- comment -->
```

I mean to clear  the comments in runtime, so end-user to not see them in the web page source code.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution, it's something that is called Blade Extending.
So, how to use it for that purpouse? I will give you an example:

```
Blade::extend(function($value)
{
    $value = preg_replace('/<!--(.+?)-->/s', '', $value); //it's removing <!-- multiline comments -->
    $value = preg_replace('/\/\*(.*?)\*\//s', '', $value); //it's removing /* multiline comments */
    $value = preg_replace('/(?<!:)\/\/.+/', '', $value); //it's removing // single line comments in JS      
    return $value;
});
```

You should place this code in **non-public/app/filters.php** or anywhere else, there is no matter, if it is executing before the view rendering.

I hope this will be useful for other people too.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using blade, you can use

```
{{-- comment --}}
```

Comment: No, this is not solution, I'm using templates, which are comming with a lot of comments in them.

Answer (score 0):

It's unstated, but I assume you want a way to leave comments that aren't rendered in HTML?

If you're using PHP templates with Laravel, just use PHP comments

```
<?php // this is my comment ?>
```

If you're using the blade template engine, just use blade comments

```
{{-- This comment will not be in the rendered HTML --}}
```

Comment: No, this is not solution, I'm using templates, which are comming with a lot of comments in them.